Traverse a graph with multiple stops from a starting point?
I have an undirected weighted graph I need to traverse from X node to a list of nodes. The list is unordered by default, meaning that the order of which nodes are traversed is not important. What's important is to have the most efficient/shortest path possible.
I am thinking of using A* algorithm to find the shortest paths between all permutations of stops and get the permutation with the shortest total travel time, but I am wondering if my approach is wrong or there's a better solution.
